# image slider with show part of previous and next image

Tags: ios, swift

i have an a collection view and i use it as image slide show, but i need display in the left previous image and in the right display next image and in the middle current image
i need it same attached picture exactly:

[image: 1]

this my code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arr.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = myCollec.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
    cell.img.image = UIImage(named: arr[indexPath.row])!
    return cell
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: myCollec.frame.width, height: myCollec.frame.height)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `sizeForItemAt` you are setting the item width to the collection view frame width.

Change that to a value that will make the cell's ***not*** full-frame-width.

Try starting with this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: myCollec.frame.width - 80.0, height: myCollec.frame.height)
}
```